# Importing csv file into postgres db using pgadmin with special characters

Tags: postgresql, csv, gtfs, pgadmin-4

I'm importing data from `csv` file into `postgres db` using `pgadmin 4`
Everything is ok but I get an issue when I try to import a file which contain some data like this

> “‘t Zand, Vlotbrug”
>
> “Dussen, `t Middeltje”

as you can see, the data contains

> `

and

> '

I also tried to import the file with utf-8 encoding but could not.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

**Updated**

Structure:

```
stop_id,stop_code,stop_name,stop_lat,stop_lon,location_type,parent_station,stop_timezone,wheelchair_boarding,platform_code,zone_id
```

Data:

```
stoparea:123953,,"De Zande, 'Koelucht'",52.5184475,5.956368,1,,,0,,
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field
CONTEXT:  COPY stops, line 69400: "stoparea:123953,,"De Zande, 'Koelucht'",52.5184475,5.956368,1,,,0,,
stoparea:120536,,"Poortvliet, Zu..."
```

**Updated 2**

Command:

> "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/psql" --command "
>   "\copy transit.stops (stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_lat,
>   stop_lon, location_type, parent_station, stop_timezone,
>   wheelchair_boarding, platform_code, zone_id) FROM
>   '/Users/tvtan/Desktop/gtfs-nl/stops.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
>   QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""

UI:

[image]

Comment: it has nothing to do with utf8, please give the structure, data sample and exact error

Comment: @VaoTsun added more information

Comment: please put columns in reproducible format and all option you use on COPY

Comment: I use pgadmin 4 to import csv file, what information do you need? @VaoTsun

Comment: hey did you fix this issue?

Comment: @Sandeep yes, please check the accpeted answer and my comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line it looks like you have defined the ESCAPE character as a single quote. The single quote appears in your data but is not escaped.

The default ESCAPE character is the same as the QUOTE character.

More information [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: I don't use the command line, I use the importing UI from pgadmin, and I have tried to set the ESCAPE character by using single quote but still error

Comment: changed escape character to quote and it works now, thanks @Paul

Comment: For fellow googlers, changing the escape character is done in pgadmin, Import/Export Dialog, "Options" tab